# How do I set the $edgeAgents schema number on a Create Deployment

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

When I create an "IoT device configuration" for deployment to multiple edge devices I can see the deployment "Configuration Details" which look ok.

However when i actually go to make a deployment it appears to set the schema of the $edgeAgent to **1,0** not 1.0 (note the comma)

eg:

```
        "modulesContent": {
            "$edgeAgent": {
                "properties.desired": {
                    "modules": {},
                    "runtime": {
                        "settings": {
                            "minDockerVersion": "v1.25"
                        },
                        "type": "docker"
                    },
                    "schemaVersion": "1,0",
```

on the documentation it says that the schemaVersion: Has to be "1.0"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-edgeagent-edgehub

When I deploy the device configuration it seems to continually come back with an IoTEdge status of

> 412 -- The deployment configuration schema version is invalid

I cant seem to find where I can change the property to be the correct value

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this effecting your development process or the production deployment?

Comment: In the meantime you can use the alternative methods:[cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-cli-at-scale) OR via [VS Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-vscode-at-scale)

Comment: @SatishBoddu-MSFT - it will effect production deployments eventually as I have not generated this file; the azure portal has. I guess I can use the CLI or VSCode and copy the generated script out of the portal and manually change the comma to a dot before running. Is this a known issue then? is it a globalisation issue in the template generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience caused, this is now fixed. Please continue/try creating New IoT Edge deployment from Azure portal-->IoT Hub and leave a comment here if you need further help on this matter. Thanks for your patience.